# Extension of a cyclic group by an abelian group

Tags: finite-groups, terminology, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-extensions

> What is meant by "an extension of a cyclic group of prime order $p$ by an abelian group of odd order relatively prime to $p$"?

Can it be a semidirect product of a cyclic group of order $p^2$ by an abelian group of order $q$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes greater than 2?

Comment: No it couldn't'; its order must be a multiple of $p$ but not of  $p^2$.

Comment: Is there a way I can get more information about extensions like that?

Comment: The order of the extension is the product of those of the normal subgroup ($p$) and the quotient group (relative to $p$) so it cannot be a multiple of $p^2$.